# Angular pass data from ion-checkbox to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, controller

I'm using ionic framework to build a web app. So I have add some  attributes and now I want to add functionality. You can see my code:

```
<div class="list card" ng-repeat="x in table">
    <div class="item item-divider">Something</div>
        <div class="item item-body">
            <p>{{x.item1}} - {{x.item2}}</p>
            <ion-checkbox>Add</ion-checkbox>
        </div>
    <div class="item item-divider">footer</div>
</div>
```

I would like to check some checkboxes to send x.item1 values to the controller or generally to a function for extended proccessing.

Thanks in advance,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a ng-change in the ion-checkbox and call a controller function from it with the argument as x.item1. Something like this:

HTML:

```
<ion-checkbox ng-model="itemChecked" ng-change="callMe(x.item1)">Add</ion-checkbox>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.callMe = function(item) {
     //do your stuff
}
```

Please note that I am not writing the complete controller syntax. If required just post a comment.

Comment: Thank you V31. Worked perfectly.

Comment: Awesome, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the angular docs. [This one](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts) will get you started. There's also a good example of data binding...

Comment: Thank you Andre for your fast reply. You are right but i got a little confused with the docs, maybe because I m a newbie yet.